# Cassandra sstableloader streaming relevant part to []

Tags: cassandra

I have got problem with sstableloader.
Command:

```
./sstableloader -d 192.168.56.101 
/home/test/Desktop/apache-cassandra-2.2.4/data/data/TestKeyspace5/tab3
```

gave me:

```
Streaming relevant part of 
/home/test/Desktop/apache-cassandra-2.2.4/data/data/TestKeyspace5/tab3/la-1-big-Data.db 
to []
```

Where the most important part is `to []`

All the files are in `apache-cassandra-2.2.4/data/data/TestKeyspace5/tab3`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please format correctly your error message - lines are too long & not visible

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that.
sstableloader doesn't work properly with cassandra 2.2.4 
When I upgrade version of cassandra to 2.2.9 it works properly.